# How to loop through an Array and gray out text in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have an `array` that gets created in `viewWillAppear` and the result in the console looks like this

```
data SecArray........... (
        (
        "<NSIndexPath 0x7f17630> 2 indexes [0, 0]"
    ),
        (
        "<NSIndexPath 0x7f96430> 2 indexes [1, 0]",
        "<NSIndexPath 0x7f99c70> 2 indexes [1, 1]",
        "<NSIndexPath 0x7f091a0> 2 indexes [1, 2]"
    ),
        (
        "<NSIndexPath 0xe43e8d0> 2 indexes [2, 0]"
    )
)
```

I am attempting to gray out the text for the items that appear in the `secArray` in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with the following code

```
        if ([self.secArray count] > 0) {

        NSLog( @"GrayText Statement...1...");

        if ([self.secArray containsObject:indexPath]) {

            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            NSLog( @"GrayText Statement...2...");

        } 


    }
```

Do Not understand why the second `if-statement` is not getting hit... what am I missing?
What would be the correct way of getting every indexPath in the secArray and graying it out ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing that your intent is to store an array of 'invalid' indices. Not going to ask why, but there might be a simpler way to achieve your intention.

Almost certainly the actual instances of `NSIndexPath` objects you have stored in your `secArray` are different to the ones that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is passing to you. (`cellForRowAtIndexPath` will create new instances of `NSIndexPath`; you're storing 'old' ones.
)

You need to compare them for equality rather than checking to see if the array contains the specific instance:

```
for (NSIndexPath *path in self.secArray) {
  if ([path compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
  }
}
```

Comment: it just crashed with NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe44a8f0'     ....regardless, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method.
From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

> A table view sends this message to its delegate just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the cell object before it is displayed. This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background color. After the delegate returns, the table view sets only the alpha and frame properties, and then only when animating rows as they slide in or out.